# Count nested categories records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following schema in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    name character varying NOT NULL,
    ancestry character varying
);

CREATE TABLE video_chats (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    name character varying NOT NULL,
    category_id bigint NOT NULL
);
```

and I have some nested categories with video chats:

```
INSERT INTO categories (id, name, ancestry)
    VALUES (1, 'Test category', null);

INSERT INTO categories (id, name, ancestry)
    VALUES (2, 'Test category subcategory', '1');    

INSERT INTO categories (id, name, ancestry)
    VALUES (3, 'Test category subcategory', '1/2');

INSERT INTO video_chats (id, name, category_id)
    VALUES (1, 'Test Video 1', '2');    

INSERT INTO video_chats (id, name, category_id)
    VALUES (2, 'Test Video 2', '3');
```

Now I want to have sql query that counts video chats for category and its sub categories. It should return following results:

- Test category - 2 Video chats
- Test category subcategory - 1 Video chat
- Test category subcategory subcategory - 1 Video chat

Here is the sqlfiddle with my schema:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f1cee/2

How can I do this in PostgreSQL?

Comment: I dont get the '1/2' value in ancestry - how is that?..

Comment: This is database example from my Ruby on Rails app. I'm using ancestry gem:  https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry

Comment: oh - I see its not devision (1/2 is half) - it is path, so the next might be `1/2/7` and so on. maybe you could also provide readable expected query results please?..

Comment: It should return rows that each of them have two columns:
`category_id`, `video_chats_count`. @VaoTsun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t=# with a as (select v.id,unnest(array_append(string_to_array(ancestry,'/')::bigint[],c.id)) cg from video_chats v join categories c on v.category_id = c.id)
select cg,count(1) from a group by cg order by cg;
 cg | count
----+-------
  1 |     2
  2 |     2
  3 |     1
(3 rows)
```

my results differ from expected:

> counts video chats for **category and** its sub categories

so *video chat id 1* belongs to category 2 and thus (because 2 is a subcategory of 1 to 1, it is vc1 categories: 2,1
*video chat 2* belongs to category 3, and thus to 2 and thus to 1, so vc2 caterories: 3,2,1

In my query it is CTE body:

```
t=# select v.id,array_append(string_to_array(ancestry,'/')::bigint[],c.id) from video_chats v join categories c on v.category_id = c.id;        id | array_append
----+--------------
  1 | {1,2}
  2 | {1,2,3}
(2 rows)
```

and thus resulting to:

- Test category(1) - 2 Video chats
- Test category subcategory(1) - 2 Video chats
- Test category subcategory subcategory(3) - 1 Video chat